# Input validation while typing in redux form field

Tags: validation, mask, redux-form

I have an input field in `redux-form` which should have a validation with mask.I want to prevent user to type hour more than 24 and minutes more than 60 minutes.

```
  <Field
    label="duratoin"
    name="duration"
    validate={[required]}
    required
    mask={[
        /[0-2]/,
        /[0-9]/,
        ':',
        /[0-6]/,
        /[0-9]/,
    ]}
    placeholder="02:00"
    component={InputMaskField}
/>
```

But with this user can type things like `29:69` . Do you have any idea ?

**Edit**

I've also tried these:

```
mask={[
          /[0-2]/,
          /[01][0-9]|2[0-3]/,
          ':',
          /[0-6]/,
          /0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9]|6[0]/,
        ]}



mask={[
          /[0-2]/,
          /{0}[0-9]|{1}[0-9]|{2}[0-3]/,
          ':',
          /[0-6]/,
          /{0}[0-9]|{1}[0-9]|{2}[0-9]|{3}[0-9]|{4}[0-9]|{5}[0-9]|{6}[0]/,
        ]}

mask={[
        /[0-2]/,
        /2?[0-4]|1?[0-9]|0?[0-9]/,
        ':',
        /[0-6]/,
        /6?[0]|[0-5]?[0-9]/,
      ]}
```